# ClickDimensions Domain Record Error on Save

Tags: dynamics-crm, clickdimension

I am following the ClickDimensions article for creating a new Domain Record, and as the article says, I first created Cname records on my domain adminstrator page. My Cname is something like:

```
host: web
value: analytics.clickdimensions.com
```

So, just like the documentation says.

Problem is, when I am on ClickDimensions > Domain Records, I fill the values for domain & web content cname and click "SAVE", I get an "Object Null reference error"  and then the yellow asp.net error page...

I have tried to find any answers online, but no luck ( I actually found one person complaining about a very similar, possibly the same, issue on their support pages, but he got no answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after sessions with support it happened to be some error on their back end.